# How to display custom error dialogue like shown in picture in android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am working on one project in which i need custom dialogue below action bar like shown in image below how can i implement custom dialogue like this to show error messages to user? please help me. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) library. The usage is straightforward

An example of usage would be

```
Crouton.makeText(this, "Error message", Style.ALERT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . yeah thats what i am looking. thanks ones again

Comment: how can i import this library in Android Studio 0.8.9 ? do you know any link where i get simple step by step procedure. thanks

Comment: It's gradle enabled. You should easily find a module in the ide

Comment: so its directly available in android studio or should i need to  import library in my project?

Comment: what I meant was that if you go inside project structure -> app, and you press on + ->   library dependency, you will find the jar in that list (it connects to maven central)